# post with ajax and php while verifying URL query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I am trying to post variables through ajax and get via php. I am getting

> Undefined index: source1
>
> Undefined index: source2

In my php echoing out of the variables, any one know what is up with my code ?

**HTML**

```
    <head>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="get.php?&uniId=3" method='post' name='sendform' onSubmit='send_value()'>
    <input type='submit' value='Test1'>
</form>

</body>
```

**Ajax**

```
function send_value() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'get.php',
        data: {
            source1: "some text",
            source2: "some text 2"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
}
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php

if (!empty($_GET{"uniId"})) {

    if ($_GET{"uniId"} == 3) {
        echo 'your logged in as '; echo $_GET['uniId'];

        $src1 = $_POST['source1'];
        $src2 = $_POST['source2'];

        echo $src1;
        echo $src2;

var_dump($_REQUEST);

    } else {
        echo 'no! no! no!';
    }
} else {
    echo "Im sorry your on the wrong page ";
}
```

Comment: Can you post here what you get back in the console as results?

Comment: Is the ajax call returning any errors?

Comment: Also debug your php side with `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_GET);` see where is stored your data.

Comment: good point +!, both var dumps return  'uniId' => string '3'

Comment: @BenjaminOats. I have pointed out your mistake . Pleae check to that in my posts answer as a new Section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data as the concatenation of the variables into the JavaScript functions.

> Pass Multiple Variables in the data of the AJAX Script.

This is one of the method to pass the data.

```
function send_value() {
    var value1 = "Post One";
    var value2 = "Post Two";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'get.php',
        data: "&data1"+value1+"&data2"+value2,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And in the PHP you need to check the data like this if you are getting `var_dump()` perfecth with the unID.

**PHP Code:**

> **Error:** You need to access the `$_REQUEST[]` or `$_GET[]` with the helpf of this brace `[]` but you have used `{}` which is entirely a blunder.

Hence You need to replace the below code like this:

Replace:

```
if ($_GET{"uniId"} == 3) {}
```

**With:**

```
 if ($_POST["uniId"] == 3) {}
```

An your Entire code will look like as follows.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["uniId"])) {
if ($_POST["uniId"] == 3) {
   // Data Process Here
}
}
?>
```

> `get.php` file will be like this on the whole:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["uniId"])) { // Your brace look wrong in this line
    if ($_POST["uniId"] == 3) { // Your brace look wrong in this line
        echo 'your logged in as '; echo $_GET['uniId'];
        $src1 = $_POST['data1']; // This should be the variable what we have used for seding purpose.
        $src2 = $_POST['data2'];
        echo $src1;
        echo $src2;
var_dump($_REQUEST);
    } else {
        echo 'no! no! no!';
    }
} else {
    echo "Im sorry your on the wrong page ";
}
```

Comment: I see thanks, the ajax looks cleaner, +1 but dose not solve the errors in the php

Comment: @BenjaminOats. You need to pass the get variables too in the data that means

Comment: again, thanks, but will dose not get the variables value1 and value2

Comment: Ensure that you have used like this `$src1 = $_POST['data1'];` in the php page

Comment: Since in the data section we have passed like this with the `data1`

Comment: @BenjaminOats you are using post to send the data but in the get.php using GET to get the data

Comment: @ArunKumaresh thank you.. Friday morning my brain is tired lol

Comment: @BenjaminOats. I have made the changes already bro. Have a check

Comment: Welcome. Its my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things here.

Your form gets submited and upon submit it call the `send_value()` callback. But since this funtion dos not return `false` the original submit of the form happens and only the parameter `uniId=3` is submitted. That is wha you don't have `$_POST['data1']` and `$_POST['data2']` set.

To make the form submit by AJAX you have to alter the HTML form-tag to

`onSubmit='return send_value()'`

and `return false` after your AJAX call.

Now you only make your AJAX call and the parameter `uniId` will not be set. You have to include it in the AJAX call.

```
function send_value() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'get.php',
        data: {
            source1: "some text",
            source2: "some text 2",
            uniId: 3
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Now in your PHP change the `$_GET{"uniId"}` to $_POST["uniId"] and it should work.

Comment: This seems a better solution and would solve all the problems, however the onclick event dose not fire